# Jquery change time format

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime-format

On my return response i am getting `start_time` like `10:00:00` in 24 hours format.I want to convert it in to two variables on `var a ="10:00"` and on `var b = "PM"` i tried it several times but not succeed. How can i do this.

Code on my php function :

```
$time = $actData->start_time; // 14:00:00
$startTime = date('h:i', strtotime($time)); // 02:00
$amPm = date('a', strtotime($time)); // PM
```

Same i want to do with scripts . How can i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you could implement the time conversion:

```js
function convertFromMilitaryToStandard(time) {
  var hour = time.slice(0,2),
      pm = hour > 12,
      hour12 = hour - (pm ? 12 : 0);
      
  //Per the request of the OP, we keep them seperate:  
  var a = (hour12 < 10 ? "0" : "") + hour12 + time.slice(2,5);
  var b = (pm ? "PM" : "AM");
  return [a,b];
}

console.log(convertFromMilitaryToStandard("10:00:00"))
console.log(convertFromMilitaryToStandard("14:00:00"))
```

Comment: thanx i want to set  time like  03:40 not 3:40.how can i do it ?

Comment: @Javed Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
function parseTime(timeString)
{
  if (timeString == '') return null;
  var d = new Date();
  var time = timeString.match(/(\d+)(:(\d\d))?\s*(p?)/i);
  hrs = parseInt(time[1],10) + ( ( parseInt(time[1],10) < 12 && time[4] ) ? 12 : 0);
  return  amPm = hrs > 11 ? 'pm' : 'am';
}

time = '14:00:00';
var date = parseTime(time);
print(date);
```